# How to assign variables to a item in a list

Tags: python

I have to design a scoreboard for a game
I have a list containing all the players in the game:

```
players = ['Starplayer', 'Ben', 'Kev', 'Cris', 'Runner', 'Heart'...etc]
```

I need to assign each of the players in this list to their level number (they all did 5 levels) and each level needs an individual score.

What I need to know is how to assign those variables to the list items.

I have a text document containing `playernames` and their `levels` and `score`:

```
Starplayer,1,19
Ben,1,20
Kev,0,20
Cris,1,19
Runner,4,19
Cris,2,15
Heart,5,16

...etc
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a dictionary of the form `{name : [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5]} `

Comment: Where would "levels" fit into that?

Comment: I briefly read up on dicts and I think that they might be exactly what I need thank you for the help

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 How do you mean?

Comment: Did each player do each level, 1 through 5 (or 0 through 4, however it's set up)? So each player simply has a record of 5 scores? Or is it something different?

Comment: Yes each player did each level and got their score for each one, each player has a record of 5 scores

Comment: Yes each player did each level and got 5 scores each. I have to display each level with its corresponding score

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a class that represents a player, with attributes `name`, `level` and `score`, and fill an array of objects of that class using the information in the text file. You can roll out your own class, or define a `namedtuple` instead. For example,

```
from collections import namedtuple

Player = namedtuple('Player', 'name, level, score')
```

This is how you can instantiate a single player:

```
# keyword arguments
p1 = Player(name='bob', level=1, score=19)
# positional arguments
p2 = Player('fred', 42, 99)
```

This is how you can instantiate one from a string corresponding to a line in your file

```
 # just for illustration. This would really come from reading the file
line = 'Starplayer,1,19'
# split line into ['Starplayer', '1', '19'] and unpack into Player
p = Player(*line.split(','))
```

Although note that this will make the `level` and `score` attributes strings. If you need integers, you'd need to do something slightly more clever.

Then you can access its attributes by name or index:

```
print p.name
print p[0]
```

Finally, this is how you could open a file and loop over its lines,

```
with open('some_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # line is a string containing the contents
        # of one line in the file
```

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that you can also define a namedtuple somewhat more naturally using the syntax `namedtuple('Player', ['name', 'level, 'score'])`

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would make a class Player like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        """put init variables here"""
        self.level=0 #or 1 whatever is first
        self.name=name
    def incrementLevel(self):
        self.level+=1
    def printName(self):
        print self.name
```

Then you could:

```
players=[]
players.append(Player("starplayer"))
players.append(Player("Ben"))
```

etc...

And then print all players for example:

```
for player in players:
    player.printName()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think beter choice would be dictionary, not list. You can use for loop in file, and separate all name,score,levels and create lists. Then again use for loop in this list and in loop create dictionary, like i[0] is key and i[1],[2] is values.